# Do we humans have an innate perception of what are secure behaviors? If yes, to what extent?

Tags: reference-request, behavior

Recently, I heard in a podcast that people enjoy booths or corners in restaurants because we have a natural preference for spaces we deem more secure (e.g. in this case, we can see the rest of the restaurant easily, less ''points of attack'' because of surrounding walls, etc.). I have heard similar rationale for several other behaviors.

This made me wonder, to what extent, do we have ingrained ''secure'' behaviors and at which point are our secure behaviors learned during our upbringing (e.g. taught by parents, school, society). For instance, something we may have been taught is ''don't get into a car with strangers.''

Are there works that have explored what secure behaviors should be transmitted vs. what behaviors seem to be ingrained by default?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. [Evolutionary Psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_psychology) looks at instinctual or [innate behaviours](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_an_official_definition_for_innate_behaviour) and there are many books and research articles on the subject. Is there a particular area of innate security behaviours you are interested in?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I wanted to get an introduction to the literature that explored firstly innate security behaviors, then learned security behaviors. I work in the area of computer security and privacy so I was wondering whether there were portions of online secure behaviors that overlapped or were similar to natural security behaviors. I was also curious to read literature on what secure behaviors are taught, where do we get security advice, and best practices for delivering this advice.